# Does 'all' add anything to a media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

Is this:

```
@media all and (min-width: @medium-min) { }
```

The same as this?:

```
@media (min-width: @medium-min) { }
```

I cant see why adding 'all' would make any difference than not specifying. However I often see the 'all' has been added. Is there an edge case that requires this?

Comment: The docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question (which is why I originally deleted my answer here immediately after submitting it), but I don't remember if I answered any earlier questions - it would seem that I didn't, because I can't find it among my previous answers. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does and by default it's set to all.

> All devices listen to this

***Available media types:***

- `all:` All devices listen to this
- `braille:` Used for braille tactile feedback devices.
- `embossed` Used for paged braille printers.
- `handheld` Used for handheld devices (Smartphones and tablets do NOT
  listen to this!).
- `print` Used for paged material and for documents viewed on screen in
  print preview mode.
- `projection` Used for projected presentations, for example projectors.
- `scree`n Used primarily for color computer screens and smartphones.
- `speech` Used for speech synthesizers.. (Whatever that may be)
- `tty` Used for media using a fixed-pitch character grid (such as
  teletypes, terminals, or portable devices with limited display
  capabilities).
- `tv` Used for television-type devices (low resolution, color,
  limited-scrollability screens, sound available).

**Reference**: http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html

Answer (score 4):

The two examples that you have are indeed equivalent. The `all` keyword is implicit in this case. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0):

> A shorthand syntax is offered for media queries that apply to all media types; the keyword ‘all’ can be left out (along with the trailing ‘and’). I.e. if the media type is not explicitly given it is ‘all’.

However...

> Is there an edge case that requires this?

Yes: both the `only` and `not` keywords require a media type to be specified in order for the media query to be valid. This is where the `all` keyword is required if you want the media query to apply to all media:

```
@media only all and (min-width: @medium-min) { }
@media not all and (min-width: @medium-min) { }
```

You can see this in the [grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax). If you look at the `media_query` production, you'll notice that the part where the media type is omitted does not include the `[ONLY | NOT]? S*` expression:

```
media_query
 : [ONLY | NOT]? S* media_type S* [ AND S* expression ]*
 | expression [ AND S* expression ]*
 ;
```

Whether this is deliberate or not is unclear to me, but implementations honor this completely and so something like `not (min-width: 300px)` will not work, and it will not [validate](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator).