# CSS media query: W3 validator fails when negating query without media type - bug or part of specification?

Tags: css, media-queries, w3c-validation

I'm validating some [CSS media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries) using the [W3C CSS Validation Service](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input).

The following query is shown as valid:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (min-resolution: 1dppx){}
```

The following negated query is shown as not valid:

```
@media not (min-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (min-resolution: 1dppx){}
```

and this query, where the media type is added to the previous, negated query is shown as valid:

```
@media not screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (min-resolution: 1dppx) {}
```

So, apparently the validation service requires that the media type ("screen" in this example) is present before accepting the "not" keyword. I could not find any reference to this behaviour in the CSS3 specification at https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ Is this a bug in the validator or part of the CSS specification?

Comment: Not a bug, just a mind-boggling restriction that I can't fathom why it is there.

Comment: This is one edge case where the all keyword is in fact required. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692635/does-all-add-anything-to-a-media-query/28692726#28692726). Also this may be a duplicate of [Why does `not (some-width: Xem)` media query never fire?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455958/why-does-not-some-width-xem-media-query-never-fire) - usually the Jigsaw validator is horrifically unreliable and buggy but in this case its validation result is consistent with 1) browser behavior, and 2) spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [syntax defined in the CSS3 Media Queries specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax) indicates that it only accepts "not" (and "only") can only be used before a media type:

```
media_query
 : [ONLY | NOT]? S* media_type S* [ AND S* expression ]*
 | expression [ AND S* expression ]*
```

(although it applies to the query as a whole)

Comment: I think you meant to say, "it requires media types to be specified when using 'not' (and 'only')"

Answer (score 0):

My guess it that you need to use a [recognized screentype](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#media-types) when using the 'not' keyword, otherwise your browser would try and apply the stylesheet to a 'not' screen

Comment: The default media type is all, not screen. Why is it so unreasonable for a browser to infer that the media query should apply to "not all and..." if the media type isn't specified, when it already does with media queries without the not keyword?

Comment: @BoltClock, my reasoning was that you needed a media_type when using the 'not' keyword, otherwise validation would see 'not' as an invalid media_type.  dontcallmedom above has the definitive answer though

Comment: Ah... that actually makes sense.